# how to find out the smallest free ID of a range

Tags: php

I have range of free IDs that can be for example between 70001 ... 72300 and between 72399 ... 72499

```
( $id > 70001 && $id < 72300 ) || ( $id > 72399 && $id < 72499 )
```

there is also a array of IDs that are forbidden let's call them (array)$forbidden

$forbidden = array(71600,71639,72489);

what is the simplest way to find out the smallest ID of this range that is not forbidden using PHP functions ?

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far?  What would the `$forbidden` array look like?

Comment: Seems like you just need a couple of `for` loops.

Comment: Is the `$forbidden` array sorted? If so, you can loop through that array and look for the first gap between elements.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question with a example of forbidden, but in real $forbidden is much longer, and yes it is sorted.

Comment: How about `min(array_diff($array, $forbidden))`

Comment: @apokryfos all I have to do for this is to express my ranges as a array. How can I express ( $id > 70001 && $id < 72300 ) || ( $id > 72399 && $id < 72499 ) as a array ?

Comment: @AnylynHax `array_merge(range(70002, 72299), range(72400, 72498))`?

Comment: @barmer thanks, I didn't knew this *range* function. It was my missing puzzle piece.